# Equivalent maxdepth for find in AIX

Tags: find, aix

I'm trying to get all files by mask in some directory without recursively searching in subdirs. There is no option `-maxdepth 0` in AIX for that.

I've heard about `-prune`, but still can't get how it works.

I guess the command should look something like

```
find dir \( ! -name dir -prune -type f \) -a -name filemask
```

but it doesn't work.

Could you please write a correct command for me and explain how it will work?

**UPD**

It seems command

```
find dir ! -path dir -prune
```

prints all files and catalogs in `dir`, but not files and catalogs in `dir/*`, so I can use it for my case.

Comment: In which way does it not work?

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas, my question is not answered in "Limit POSIX find to specific depth". In my case there is no need to use `-path`  for `find`

Comment: Yes, I've reopened. It's unclear what you're problem is and what you want to do. Beside the superfluous `(`/`)` and the `dir/dir` issue mentioned in my answer, it seems to me your answer should work at what I think you want to do (find files called `filemask` in `dir` (and `dir` only)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd want:

```
find dir/. ! -name . -prune -type f -name filemask
```

Or:

```
find dir ! -path dir -prune -type f -name filemask
```

To find the regular files called `filemask` in `dir` without searching in sub-directories of `dir`.

With `find dir ! -name dir -prune`, you'd have issues if there was a `dir/dir` directory.

The `dir/.` approach works around that because `find` will not come across any other file called `.` than that `dir/.` file passed as argument.

The `-path` approach works around it by looking at the file path of the files (as opposed to just the name), `-path dir` will match on `dir`, but not on `dir/dir` (so `dir` will be the only directory it will not prune). `-path` may not be available in older versions of AIX though.

More generally, for the standard equivalent of GNU's `-maxdepth n`, see [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](/a/330372)

Comment: Could you please explain how it works? In the first method file name looks like `dir/./filename` (with dot!), It looks weird. OK, try understand the second one... Does `!` relate to `-path dir` only?

Comment: @Vikora, see edit.

Comment: `Find ... -path ...` executes without errors, but there is not `-path` in `man find`.

Comment: @Vikora, `-path` (initially a BSD extension also supported by GNU) was only added in the 2008 edition of the POSIX standard. Possibly AIX added it for conformance some time after that but forgot to update the documentation.

Comment: Confirming Stéphane's [comment above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372994/equivalent-maxdepth-for-find-in-aix#comment663370_373001) that `find` in AIX 6.1 and 7.1 both support `-path` and neither have it documented in their corresponding man pages.

Answer (score 4):

In AIX you can use `-prune` option.

```
find ./* -prune
```

Comment: An explanation on why/how the command works will make this a great answer.