# How to check duplicate commands in $PATH?

Tags: command-line, path

For example, youtube-dl has different ways to install it onto machine. I downloaded/installed it multiple times in not-same ways inadvertently, so that resulted that I have several youtube-dl executables in my $PATH directories, `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`, `/home/username/.local/bin/youtube-dl`, and `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`. So even I installed upgrade version "2021.01.03", `youtube-dl --version` shows me "2020.07.28", because youtube-dl in other directory in $PATH somehow overrided it.

So here, I want to check all of installed same-name files in $PATH so I can check their versions at once and can see which one is the latest, current one and which one should be deleted. So, Is there a way or CLI tool to do that? Thanks.

Comment: `whereis youtube-dl` or `which youtube-dl` might get you started

Comment: `whereis` did work for me for this, amazing. Thanks @Panki

Comment: This has been asked before, please see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command/149054#149054), or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232009/how-to-handle-duplicates-in-my-path-variable) for several solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactively, I would use:

```
ls -l $(type -ap youtube-dl)
```

to find the locations and timestamps of all the `youtube-dl` programs in my $PATH.

Of course, this doesn't work for executables that have spaces in their names, but `youtube-dl` isn't one of them.

Comment: This solution does not work recursively, or through the $PATH.

Comment: The question didn't ask for a recursive solution, and $PATH doesn't work that way. Why do you say it doesn't work for the $PATH variable?

Answer (score 2):

In order to visit the PATH directories in order and list the location of files that would be executed you can use the `which` command:

```
$ which -a command_name
```

Comment: I have to draw your attention to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/117549

Answer (score 0):

The following script will output a list of duplicated executables found in the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable.

It does this by creating a tab-delimited two-column list of executables, where the first column is the directory pathname and the second is the filename of an executable.

This list is read by a simple `awk` program that counts how many times each executable is found and that collects all directory pathnames for each of them in a tab-delimited string.

At the end, the `awk` code outputs each executable whose exact name was found more than once, together with the tab-delimited list of directory pathnames where it was found.  The directories will be listed in the order they were searched, i.e. an executable would be picked from the *first* directory listed if used without an explicit path on the command line (given the current value of `$PATH`).

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# turn off filename globbing, and
# split strings in unquoted variables on colons
set -f; IFS=:

# set the positional parameters to the list of
# directories in the PATH variable
set -- $PATH

# turn on filename globbing again
# (leave IFS as is, it won't affect anything else here)
set +f

# loop over those directories and do the things
for dir do
        for pathname in "$dir"/*; do
                [ -x "$pathname" ] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$dir" "${pathname##*/}"
        done
done |
awk -F '\t' '
{
        dir[$2] = ( dir[$2] == "" ? $1 : dir[$2] "\t" $1 )
        count[$2]++
}
END {
        for (util in dir)
                if (count[util] > 1)
                        printf "%s\t%s\n", util, dir[util]
}'
```

Example run on my OpenBSD system, passing the output through `column -t` to format it nicely, and sorting it:

```
$ sh script | column -t | sort
banner       /usr/bin                /usr/games
bash         /home/myself/local/bin  /usr/local/bin
bashbug      /home/myself/local/bin  /usr/local/bin
chgrp        /bin                    /usr/sbin
chown        /usr/sbin               /sbin
clang        /usr/bin                /usr/local/bin
clang++      /usr/bin                /usr/local/bin
clang-cpp    /usr/bin                /usr/local/bin
ld.lld       /usr/bin                /usr/local/bin
llvm-config  /usr/bin                /usr/local/bin
python3      /home/myself/local/bin  /usr/local/bin
python3.8    /home/myself/local/bin  /usr/local/bin
sysctl       /usr/sbin               /sbin
zsh          /home/myself/local/bin  /usr/local/bin
```

The output tells me that if I start `bash` on the command line, it will be picked up from `/home/myself/local/bin`, and that I have another `bash` executable in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check all of installed same-name files in `$PATH`

Here's another suggestion, using `find` across the `$PATH` to get the file names, and `awk` to match up duplicates. You can roll it up into a single line if you want, but I've spread it across several here for readability,

```
( IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f ) |    # See below for alternative without maxdepth
    awk -F/ '
        {
            p[$NF] = p[$NF] "\n" $0;           # Save the pathname ($NF is last component)
            h[$NF] ++                          # Count this instance of the filename
        }
        END {
            for (f in h) {
                if (h[f] >1) { print p[f] }    # Print list iff we have multiple hits
            }
        }
    '
```

If your `find` doesn't have the `-maxdepth` action, you can replace that first line with [this expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373001/100397)

```
( IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do find dir ! -path dir -prune -type f; done ) |
```

Unreadable but rolled up one-line version

```
(IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f)|awk -F/ '{p[$NF]=p[$NF]"\n"$0;h[$NF]++}END{for(f in h){if(h[f]>1){print p[f]}}}'
```